# How to test for rows containing one of many values?

Tags: r

Is there a faster way to complete the following? I would like to test for 30 different values rather than simply the 3 shown below.

keeps<-cost [cost$GEO.id2 == 36081004500 | cost$GEO.id2 == 36081004700 | cost$GEO.id2 == 36081005900]

Comment: In your introductory R resources look for examples using the `match` and `%in%` functions. And don't forget to use a comma avter the logical tests. At the moment you are probably going to select the first column instead of the rows you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%in%`,

```
keeps = cost[cost$GEO.id2 %in% c(36081004500, 36081004700, 36081005900), ]
```

Best, of course, if there's a pattern it what you want to keep:

```
tests = seq(from = 36081004500, length.out = 30, by = 200)
keeps = cost[cost$GEO.id2 %in% tests, ]
```